# Dealing with Numerical Issues from Computing Weighted Sample Covariance Matrix

Tags: covariance-matrix, weighted-data, numerics

I have vector-valued samples $\mathbf{x}_1, \mathbf{x}_2, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_N$ with normalized weights $w_1, \ldots, w_N$. I'm trying to compute a weighted sample covariance matrix:
$$
\sum_i w_i (\mathbf{x}_i - \bar{\mathbf{x}}) (\mathbf{x}_i - \bar{\mathbf{x}})^T = \sum_i w_i \mathbf{x}_i\mathbf{x}_i^T - \bar{\mathbf{x}}\bar{\mathbf{x}}^T,
$$
where $\bar{\mathbf x} = \sum w_i \mathbf x_i$. Usually I use the expression on the right hand side because it is a function of weighted averages of the data. However, I have noticed that these covariance matrices aren't always positive definite numerically, even though they should be, theoretically speaking.

How exactly does this numerical error creep in, and what can I do about it? Why is this fix preferable (I've seen several suggestions after an internet search)? FWIW: I would prefer not to use the expression on the left hand side because it would involve changing some code I'd rather not change.

Comment: @amoeba yes, sorry I forgot to mention that. I will update the question shortly.

Comment: After the update: I am not sure this is answerable without a reproducible example. As you say, this should always be positive definite. BTW, what exactly do you mean by "not always positive definite"? If there are some tiny negative eigenvalues for whatever reason, you can set them to zero. Or do you get *large* negative eigenvalues? I would suspect a bug.

Comment: @amoeba yes, usually they're slightly negative; however, once I got a -3. A bug hasn't been ruled out. However, increasing the number of samples seems to fix the problem. Example is still to come.